# Where should the template view file for the login function go?

Tags: cakephp, authentication

I am trying to follow the [Simple Authentication and Authorization Application](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html) tutorial
but it is not clear where the template view file for the login function (below) is supposed to go.

```
<div class="users form">
<?php echo $this->Session->flash('auth'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->create('User'); ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?php echo __('Please enter your username and password'); ?></legend>
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('username');
        echo $this->Form->input('password');
    ?>
    </fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Login')); ?>
</div>
```

When put in app/View/Users/login.ctp , users/add causes the following error:

```
Error: The view for UsersController::index() was not found.
Error: Confirm you have created the file: app\View\Users\index.ctp
```

When app/View/Users/login.ctp is renamed to app/View/Users/index.ctp , users/add indicates

> The user has been saved

But going back to the blog tutorial root and attempting to do an add causes

```
Error: The view for UsersController::login() was not found.
Error: Confirm you have created the file: C:\csvn\www\jack\app\View\Users\login.ctp
```

So: where should the template view file for the login function go? In index, login, or some other .ctp?

*Edit: add app/Controller/UsersController.php code*

```
class UsersController extends AppController {

    public function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Auth->allow('add'); // Letting users register themselves
    }

    public function login() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            if ($this->Auth->login()) {
                $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
            }
        }
    }

    public function logout() {
        $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
    }

    public function index() {
        $this->User->recursive = 0;
        $this->set('users', $this->paginate());
    }

    public function view($id = null) {
        $this->User->id = $id;
        if (!$this->User->exists()) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid user'));
        }
        $this->set('user', $this->User->read(null, $id));
    }

    public function add() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->User->create();
            if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved'));
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        }
    }

    public function edit($id = null) {
        $this->User->id = $id;
        if (!$this->User->exists()) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid user'));
        }
        if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
            if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved'));
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        } else {
            $this->request->data = $this->User->read(null, $id);
            unset($this->request->data['User']['password']);
        }
    }

    public function delete($id = null) {
        if (!$this->request->is('post')) {
            throw new MethodNotAllowedException();
        }
        $this->User->id = $id;
        if (!$this->User->exists()) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid user'));
        }
        if ($this->User->delete()) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('User deleted'));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('User was not deleted'));
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }
}
```

*Edit: add AppController*

```
<?php
App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');

class AppController extends Controller {
    public $helpers = array('Session');

    public $components = array(
        'Session',
        'Auth' => array(
            'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'index'),
            'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home'),
            'authorize' => array('Controller') // Added this line
        )
    );

    public function isAuthorized($user) {
        // Admin can access every action
        if (isset($user['role']) && $user['role'] === 'admin') {
            return true;
        }

        // Default deny
        return false;
    }

    public function beforeFilter() {
        $this->Auth->allow('index', 'view');
    }
}
```

Comment: It may be helpful to post your controller code, The login function should go in the login.ctp. Given that in your user controller you have login function with the code from the example

Comment: I'm guessing the user is being logged in and is being redirected to `UsersController index.ctp` upon successful log in (please post `AppController` code to confirm). And the issue is just that you don't have the view for the index created yet and not anything with the login function not working. The login form should be located at `View/Users/login.ctp` for sure

Comment: I just re-read your question. So you're not having any issue with actually logging into the site, it's just that your `add()` gets messed up? Do you have the `add.ctp` view file?

Comment: I still think the issue is that you are missing the `index.ctp` view file. If you are trying to add a user then that would explain why you get the error message of the missing view when your login form is located at `View/Users/login.ctp` because you have no file located at `View/Users/index.ctp` which is where the `add()` action is redirecting you to after adding a user successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pulled from comment conversation...

"I still think the issue is that you are missing the `index.ctp` view file. If you are trying to add a user then that would explain why you get the error message of the missing view when your login form is located at `View/Users/login.ctp` because you have no file located at `View/Users/index.ctp` which is where the `add()` action is redirecting you to after adding a user successfully."

Comment: Yes. I glossed over this comment in the tutorial: **In the same way we created the views for our blog posts or by using the code generation tool, we implement the views. For the purpose of this tutorial, we will show just the add.ctp**. I added /app/View/Users/index.ctp with just an `Add User` link.